# How to send a tweet to a twitter acount from my iPhone app and comply with twitter as of 2011?

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth

I need to simply send a tweet to a users account from my iPhone app, but allot of what I have looked at seems a bit heavy for what I need to do, also everything I have found seems it is a bit old and I'm worried that I add something that might not comply to the new twitter or apple. I have looked at oauthconsumer, MPOAuth, Twitter-OAuth-iPhone(ben gottlieb)etc, but I need something lightweight and up to date with all of twitter and apples requirements. All I need is a couple of suggestions to point me in the right direction, maybe one of the projects I have mentioned will work but I need some confirmation. Thanks, Brett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just finished doing this myself. It's a bit meddlesome but not hard.

First, you will need to apply for xAuth permissions on your twitter app.

Info here:
http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth

I then implemented this really cool and well implemented Twitter Auth System.
http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks so much, I will get on it and keep you updated. Thanks, Brett

Answer (score 2):

You can Use ShareKit

[ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/)  is a social networking API which enables iOS users to integrate Facebook, Twitter, Google Reader and send mails,etc in a very simple and easy manner.

Hope this helps.